# posicionar atras y encima

Tags: css

Quiero crear la siguiente figura:

```
       h
       h
hhhhhhhh
```

pero no puedo, este es mi codigo:

```css
.car{
width:100px;}

.Loader {
  width: 100px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: red;
}

.Back {
  width: 10px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  float:right;
}
```

```html
<div class="car">
<div class="Back">
</div>
<div class="pala">
</div>
<div class="Loader">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: No entiendo muy bien tu figura, que es eso ?

Comment: @CamiloVasquez ya puse mi figura, mi codigo lo hace pero alreves

Comment: ¿es necesario que sea con todos esos divs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para lograr lo que deseas debes jugar con `position: relative` y `position: absolute`, y con las coordenadas `top`, `left`, `right` y `bottom` en los elementos, de la siguiente forma:

Espero haber sido claro con la explicación, si tienes dudas con gusto te las resuelvo.

```css
.car{
  width:100px;
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
}

.Loader {
  width: 100px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.Back {
  width: 10px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="car">
  <div class="Back"></div>
  <div class="pala"></div>
  <div class="Loader"></div>
</div>
```

**Nota:** Es importante recalcar que el padre de los elementos debe de tener `position: relative` para que a los elementos hijos (que tienen `position: absolute`) se les apliquen las coordenadas en base al tamaño de su padre.